# bar plot without for-loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

is it possible to get rid of the cycle?

Here is my input data

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frac = [0.75, 0.6093, 0.7025, 0.0437, 0.1]

plt.figure()
orange, blue = '#fd7f28', '#2678b2'
```

Then this ugly cycle

```
for i in range(0,5):
    plt.bar(0.5+i, frac[i], color=blue)
    plt.bar(0.5+i, 1-frac[i], bottom=frac[i], color=orange)
```

.

```
plt.xticks([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5], ['AR', 'BR', 'PE', 'RU', 'US'], 
rotation='horizontal')
plt.ylabel("Fraction")
plt.xlabel("")

plt.show()
```

[image: It works, but i don't like it]

Can I do it without a cycle?

Also. when bar is labelled iy outputs this legend
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you call a "*cycle*" is commonly called a *loop* (or a for-loop in this case).

You can easily get rid of it. [As per the documentation, `bar()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) accepts sequences of scalars (or vectors) as inputs for `x=`, `height=` and `bottom=`. Your code can therefore be simplified as:

```
plt.bar(range(len(frac)), frac, bottom=0., color=blue, label="gmail")
plt.bar(range(len(frac)), 1-frac, bottom=frac, color=orange, label="hotmail")
```

for this to work out of the box, I transformed your `frac` list into a numpy array, which allows you to do arithmetics like "`1-frac`".

Full code:

```
frac = np.array([0.75, 0.6093, 0.7025, 0.0437, 0.1])
orange, blue = '#fd7f28', '#2678b2'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(range(len(frac)), frac, bottom=0., color=blue, label="gmail")
ax.bar(range(len(frac)), 1-frac, bottom=frac, color=orange, label="hotmail")
ax.legend(loc=5, frameon=True)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(frac)))
ax.set_xticklabels(['AR', 'BR', 'PE', 'RU', 'US'])
plt.ylabel("Fraction")
plt.xlabel("")
```

[image]